# How to know whether my wordpress site is secure or not?

Tags: php, wordpress, spam

I am using a theme which I downloaded from a website(not from the vendor because its paid) and that theme is in my wordpress site, but someone told that there may be some code injected to hack my site.

How do I check that it is safe theme.

Please reply.

Comment: You should hire one developer !

Comment: i can't buy theme, so how can i hire a developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) it's a popular WordPress security plugins

Comment: Please add some more detail.

Comment: just run WordFence's scan and it should tell if there's a threat

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps explained how to secure your WordPress website https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/secure-your-wordpress-website/
You can use the SSL certificate for your website it will secure everything not only website also you can use the security.

The next change your wp-admin directory in the URL set up some security plugins which will protect your website.

check security plugins here http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/7-best-wordpress-security-plugins/#gref

Thanks

Comment: thanks @Pankaj Lilan and thanks to all for providing solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try scanning your site using [this](https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/) tool. It will show you a report of what the possible attacks on your site are and where are they possible.